# python re.split gives different results depending on char group order

Tags: python, regex

```py
>>> import re
>>> s = "i'm happy 7 times"
>>> re.split(r' ',s)
["i'm", 'happy', '7', 'times']
>>> re.split(r"[, -]",s)
["i'm", 'happy', '7', 'times']
>>> re.split(r"[, -:]",s)
['i', 'm', 'happy', '', '', 'times']
```

Added a colon to the char group and the apostrophe and the digit become targets for the `split`.

```py
>>> re.split(r"[:, -]",s)
["i'm", 'happy', '7', 'times']
```

Moved the colon to the front of the group and got the expected result.

Put a colon in the string:

```py
>>> s = "i'm happy 7 times: again"
>>> re.split(r"[:, -]",s)
["i'm", 'happy', '7', 'times', '', 'again']
```

I can't find anything in the re documentation about colons having a meaning in a char group. Is this correct behaviour?

I'm using:

```
Python 3.11.4 (tags/v3.11.4:d2340ef, Jun  7 2023, 05:45:37) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

Comment: Looks like I just described it working properly! Didn't see the forest for the trees. thanks

Comment: I expect that many, if not most, readers will immediately spot your problem and expect the question to be closed as a duplicate of an earlier question, as they've seen variants of your question before. That's no reason for you to refrain from asking the question (many of us have been bitten by that gotcha), but imo the appropriate response by readers is to simply pin a comment explaining the problem, as @Andrej did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with the colon, but the dash. From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) (emphasis mine):

> Ranges of characters can be indicated by giving two characters and separating them by a '-', for example [a-z] will match any lowercase ASCII letter, [0-5][0-9] will match all the two-digits numbers from 00 to 59, and [0-9A-Fa-f] will match any hexadecimal digit. **If `-` is escaped (e.g. `[a\-z]`) or if it’s placed as the first or last character (e.g. `[-a]` or `[a-]`), it will match a literal `'-'`.**

In your first example the `-` is the last character, therefore it doesn't indicate a range.